# Python: use Type Hints together with Annotations

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting

In Python, we all know [Type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), which became available from 2015:

```py
def greet(name: str) -> str:
    return "Hello, " + name
```

and we also know [Function Annotations](https://peps.python.org/pep-3107/), in particular here I am referring to textual annotations like:

```py
def greet(name: "The name of the person to greet") -> str:
    return "Hello, " + name
```

But *is it possible to use Type Hints **together** with a textual function annotation*?

For example:

```py
def greet(name: str, "The name of the person to greet") -> str:
    return "Hello, " + name
```

This last one throws an error.

I cannot seem to find any source in PEP or Python docs about whether this would be possible or not. Although I haven't searched particularly deeply, I still would appreciate a source on potential answers.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you're trying to do here. I guess you mean to restrict `name` to certain names only? for example like one of Jon or Jackson, but not another name.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear. It asks about being able to have one or more arguments with an assigned Type Hint annotation plus a "description" string annotation. See the answers below which all understood the question, in particular [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71478072/3873799), which I think I will accept. In a nutshell, I think that [PEP 593 – Flexible function and variable annotations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0593/) may be the right answer: it adds an `Annotated` type to the typing module so you can decorate inputs with both Type hints and context-specific metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Samwise said, type checkers will not understand if the annotation is a tuple of the type and description (or whatever other metadata you wish to attach). [PEP 593 – Flexible function and variable annotations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0593/) addresses exactly this via the following:

```
from typing import Annotated

@dataclass
class Description:
    x: str

def greet(name: Annotated[str, Description("The name of the person to greet")]) -> str:
    return "Hello, " + name
```

The reason we introduce a wrapper class `Description` is so it's clear that the written string is intended to be a description consumed by us, and so other libraries that analyze annotations do not get confused in case they use `str` for their own metadata.

Then, per [typing.Annotated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated), you can use `typing.get_type_hints(name, include_extras=True)` to get the description at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Since an annotation can be any expression (as far as the Python interpreter is concerned), you can technically do something like using a tuple as your annotation:

```
def greet(name: (str, "The name of the person to greet")) -> str:
    return "Hello, " + name
```

which shows up in the function's annotations dict exactly as you'd expect:

```
>>> greet.__annotations__
{'name': (<class 'str'>, 'The name of the person to greet'), 'return': <class 'str'>}
```

However, this is only *useful* if you have tooling that knows what it means.  As far as I know, no existing static type checker, linter, doc generator, etc is going to recognize an annotation that's a tuple of a type and a description.

Practically speaking, I'd recommend using the annotation for the type *only*, since that's overwhelmingly the standard usage, and using comments or docstrings for additional information.